# How to split up elements of a list separated by ],[ in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like :

```py
mylist=[[["A","B"],["A","C","B"]],[["A","D"]]]
```

and I want to return :

```py
mylist=[["A","B"],["A","C","B"],["A","D"]]
```

Using the `split()` function returns an error of :

> list object has no attribute split

Therefore, I am unsure how I should split the elements of this list.
Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to do is a version of "flattening".  If you use that term in your searching, you'll learn a lot about this.  BTW - this question does not seem to have anything to do with networkx.  Can we remove that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for-loop in order to do this.
Here is an example code:

```
output = []
for list_element in my_list:
    for single_list in list_element:
        output.append(single_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you think *splitting* will do any good for you; after all, you are -- if anything -- *merging* the second layer lists. But flattenening by one level can be done by a comprehension:

```
mylist = [inner for outer in mylist for inner in outer]
# [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C', 'B'], ['A', 'D']]
```

One util to (maybe a matter of taste) simplify this is `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

mylist = list(chain(*mylist))
```

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by explaining why the original code does not work. The `],[` you see in the string representation of the list are purely visualisation. There is no need to split the list, as it is already split into its elements in your computer's memory. I do like the suggestion to use `itertools.chain`, which explains what you want (chain the inner items into a new list), without a lot of distracting control flow.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are talking about. There is no string representation of any list in the question.

Comment: I mean that it appears to me from the title that the original poster thinks that somehow `],[` is a separator between the lists, on which to split the list. But as it is indeed a list there is no need to split as you said in your answer.

Comment: Possibly, there is no telling what goes on in the mind of the beginner coder :D

Comment: Ahh okay thank you for clarifying this (I am a beginner so I appreciate the explanation- sorry if the question is obvious to most!)